# How to override wizard's method on odoo 12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, odoo-accounting, odoo-wizard

I am trying to override a single method on wizard's class that gets executed when the user click submit.

*account_consolidation_custom/wizard/CustomClass.py*

```
class AccountConsolidationConsolidate(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'account.consolidation.consolidate_custom'
    _inherit = 'account.consolidation.base'

    def get_account_balance(self, account, partner=False, newParam=False):
    ....my custom code...
```

*account_consolidation_custom/__manifest_.py*

```
{
    'name': "account_consolidation_custom",

    'summary': """""",

    'description': """
    """,

    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.1',

    'depends': ['base','account_consolidation'],

    # always loaded
    'data': [],
}
```

The method's name is exactly the same as the original, but when I click on the submit button, nothing seems to happen, is still calling the method from the base module instead of the custom.

Do you know how to get only one method overwritten instead of the whole wizard class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new wizard/transient model when giving different values to the private attributes `_name` and `_inherit`. Instead you should use the original odoo model name `account.consolidation.consolidate` to both attributes or just remove the `_name` attribute completely.

Odoo has it's own inheriting mechanism, which is managed by the three class attributes `_name`, `_inherit` and `_inherits`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it stills the same after doing those changes, base method is still getting executed, not custom.

Comment: Do you have all `__init__.py` files?

Comment: Yes, I have an ```__init__.py``` inside the wizard folder with the file name imported, and then I am calling the wizard ```from . import wizard``` on the main ```__init__.py```

Comment: Ehrm, the original model is not a Transient but an AbstractModel.

Comment: Ah, and you have to extend its inheriting transient model `account.consolidation.consolidate`. I have changed the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I was able to make it work with the following:   ```class AccountConsolidationConsolidate(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'account.consolidation.consolidate' ```,                                              I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work using the following code:

```
class AccountConsolidationConsolidate(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'account.consolidation.consolidate'

   def get_account_balance(self, account, partner=False, newParam=False):
    ....my custom code...
```

After that I was able to overwrite the base methods.